# open a url on click intent

Tags: android, onclick

I can't find a way to make this code work, please help.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
Toast.makeText(Main.this, "ID '" + o.get("id")+"' url '"+ o.get("url") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           

Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",Uri.parse(o.get("url")));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: the thing is i want the uri.parse must read  the urlk from the o.get("url")

Answer (score 0):

open URL in WebView

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) { 
Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

}

open URL in Default Browser

```
public void openNewActivity(View view) { 
Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
startActivity(myWebLink);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is wrong, it should be:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.intent.action.VIEW,Uri.parse(o.get("url"))); 
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

And yes don't forget to add **INTERNET** Permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it does not work, now i get a "android.intent cannot be resolved to a variable" error, please help